# Incorporating attribute table into python

Tags: python, arcmap

I am working in python with ArcMap & had a question. Is there a way to import the data from an attribute table into python, and if you can how do you select which attributes to print?

Thank You

Comment: Read here http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Accessing_data_using_cursors/002z0000001q000000/

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question

Answer (score 0):

A clean looking way of presenting an attribute table in python can be executed through a pandas dataframe...especially if you are working with shapefiles. The input must be a dbf file.

```
# Pandas Option, python 2.7
import arcpy, os, pandas
inTable = r'.dbf'
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(inTable))
outTable = 'table.xls'
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(inTable, outTable)
df = pandas.read_excel(outTable)
df.head() # Shows first five records of attribute table
```

Using SearchCursors and UpdateCursors is also an option if you want to update fields and work directly with the shapefile.

```
# SearchCursor option, python 2.7
import arcpy, os
shapefile = r'.shp'
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, '*')
attributes = []
for row in cursor:
    attributes.append(row)
```

If you want to find a specific record by a certain field name...for example ID 50...

```
for record in attributes:
    if record[0] == 50:
        print record
```